# Google map geocoder, accessing global variable in it

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I have to find latlong from address, and i want to load all them in a global array varibale, 
here what i am doing

```
  for(i=0; i<locations.length; i++){

    var paddress = locations[i]['address'] +','+locations[i]['postal_code'] + ', ' +locations[i]['district'] + ',' + locations[i]['country'];
    var  pgeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    pgeocoder.geocode( { 'address': paddress}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            Storelatlong[i] = results[0].geometry.location;

        }
    });
    }


    alert(Storelatlong.length);
```

But it always return length 0, if i alert inside the geocoder function it gives latlong fine, is there any other way to assing the data to a global variable from inside the geocoder , thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that by the time that you get the response from google i is not defined any more, try fixing it with a closure, something like this

```
pgeocoder.geocode( { 'address': paddress}, (function(index) {
      return function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            Storelatlong[index] = results[0].geometry.location;
        };
      }(i))
);
```

Comment: No success still giving length 0

Comment: did you debug it? what's the value of index when the response function is being run?